# Restrict file system access in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

We have an application running in EC2 instance. We have to give the product as AMI to customers. Currently they can access the file-system. But I want to restrict others to open the file-system.

Is there any way around to restrict them to access the contents? 
Help needed !!!

Comment: What "others" are you talking about? Customers?

Comment: AMIs provided through the AWS Marketplace can be restricted, but not normal AMIs.

Comment: @JakubKania yeah customers ...

Comment: oh okey @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not possible.

If you read AWS docs on how to protect a *paid* AMI, you'll also read that it's not really possible.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonDevPay/latest/DevPayDeveloperGuide/PaidAMIs.html#EC2AssociateProductCode

What you might want to consider: encrypting and hiding the decryption key or obfuscating the source you wish to protect.

Comment: Thanks for the info @deviavir